# VS Code extension how to edit in context?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Her is the class I use automatically capitalize `true`, `false`, ...

```
export class StUpdater {
    private _lines: number;
    private _strings: Array<string>;

    constructor() {
        this._lines = 0;
        this._strings = ['true', 'false', 'exit', 'continue', 'return'];
    }

    Update(Cntx: boolean = false) {
        let editor = window.activeTextEditor;
        if (!editor || (editor.document.languageId != 'st')) {
            window.showErrorMessage('No editor!')
            return;
        }

        let doc = editor.document;

        if (Cntx == false) {
            if (this._lines >= doc.lineCount) {
                this._lines = doc.lineCount;
                return;
            }
            this._lines = doc.lineCount;

            let AutoFormat = workspace.getConfiguration('st').get('autoFormat');

            if (!AutoFormat) {
                return;
            }
        }


        let edit = new WorkspaceEdit();

        for (let line = 0; line < doc.lineCount; line++) {
            const element = doc.lineAt(line);
            for (let i = 0; i < this._strings.length; i++) {
                let str = this._strings[i];
                let last_char = 0;
                while (element.text.indexOf(str, last_char) >= 0) {
                    let char = element.text.indexOf(str, last_char);
                    last_char = char + str.length;
                    edit.replace(
                        doc.uri,
                        new Range(
                            new Position(line, char),
                            new Position(line, last_char)
                        ),
                        str.toUpperCase()
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        return workspace.applyEdit(edit);
    }

    public dispose() {

    }
}
```

This code works fine, but I do not want to replace it inside the string or comment. How do I do that? I cannot find preg version of replace and even if I do, in one line I do not know if it is comment or not if it is multiple line comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want capitalize only certain elements (identifiers probably), but not words in comments or strings, correct? That requires to identify lexical elements in the text, which is a mapping of a range of letters to a lexical type. This is usually done by [a lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). It's not difficult to write one by hand which walks over the characters on top of your current processing and find those ranges that can be manipulated.

Comment: That barely answer my question. I have exact example of what I have now. If I where to parse document as a text and use standard JS functions, I do not think I would have a problems.What I want is to use VS Code API or Formatter API to achieve that.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Then I guess there's no solution for you. AFAIK there are no APIs that can be used by an extension to get lexical informations for a text.